# unable to use zsh/bash in Jenkins Execute Shell

Tags: ios, bash, jenkins, cocoapods, zsh

I am trying to run iOS builds in a remote Mac mini connected as an agent to Jenkins master running on Linux server. I have all the dependencies installed and env variables set up via .zshrc(zsh is the default shell in catalina and above).

When I run scripts(npm install, pod install and so on) through `Execute Shell` option in Jenkins Freestyle project, it throws `npm command not found`/ `pod command not found`. Even when I shebang with `/bin/zsh` at the start of script, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to switch shell to zsh/bash or import all configurations into sh in the jenkins build process?

Comment: Hi, what is the default SHELL of the user you are using to connect your mac slave?(assuming it is via ssh)

Comment: zsh(default shell in MacOS Catalina)

Slave is connected through `Java Web Start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins leverage the 'rc' file when it connects to the slave (via ssh) and load the env variable (This also means when you will change anything in the rc file you need to disconnect and reconnect the slave to load the changes). Now it depends on the default SHELL set for the User you used to connect the slave. You need to check that and align the env variable accordingly in the right rc file.

In the current situation, if you don't want to change anything you could also do a

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

at the start of your script. This will load the env vars defined in that file

One more way is to set the env variable for a node is under "Node Properties" in node configuration.

Comment: I had to use `source ~/.zshrc` as you suggested in a build script executed through sh. But the default shell for the User is zsh for sure.(which is also default as the slave machine runs on MacOS Catalina).

Comment: Ok then I think it is more of which shell Jenkins start, if you will move your content to .bashrc it will definitely load it while connecting to that slave as it does for me (for a mac machine on Catalina) and that way you can get rid of that source command in your script which I understand is not a neat solution.

Comment: By default jenkins starts with `sh` shell(Atleast in my case). `.bashrc` didn't work for me. May be it depends on our Jenkins master setup. Do you have your master run in the same machine as slave or different?

Answer (score 1):

I've succeed run script in zsh shell. Here is my solution,

```
sh('''#!/bin/zsh -l
source ${HOME}/.zshrc
pod install
''')
```

or

```
sh script: '''#!/bin/zsh -l
source ${HOME}/.zshrc
pod install
''', label: 'pod install'
```

you may change to bash as you need.